# Is every group of order 117 abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a Group of order 117. Then is $G$ abelian?

Note that $117 = 13*3^2$ and that $13 \equiv 1 \bmod 3$, so [A group of order $p^2q$ will be abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147540/finite-group-of-order-p2q) doesn't help.

Comment: The statement is false. There are non-abelian groups of order $117$.

Comment: [This link](http://www-groups.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~colva/topics/solns5.pdf) contains a classification, which includes non-abelian examples.

Comment: $\langle\, a,b\mid a^{13}=b^3=1, ab=b^3a\,\rangle$ is non-abelian of order $39$.

Comment: I'm going to edit the question so it contains a statement which can be proved to be not true.

Comment: No. $117$ is not in [OEIS/A051532](https://oeis.org/A051532). See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556811/does-there-exist-an-n-such-that-all-groups-of-order-n-are-abelian.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is false.

Notice that $C_{13}<G$ and by Sylow's theorem there is a subgroup $P$ of size $9$ as well.  Consider $\textrm{Aut}(C_{13})\cong C_{12}$, we can easily find a non-trivial homomorphism $\phi$ from $P$ to $\textrm{Aut}(C_{13})$.  Thus we can form a non-trivial semidirect product of $C_{13}$ with $P$ using $\phi$.

Explicitly let $P=C_3^2$ so elements are tuples $(g,h)$ with integer entries taken $\mod 3$ and let $\textrm{Aut}(C_{13})=\langle x\rangle$. We can then define $\Phi:C_3^2\rightarrow \textrm{Aut}(C_{13})$ by $(g,h)\mapsto x^{4g}$.