# Show $xy=yx$ for all $x\in H$ and $y\in K$

Tags: group-theory

Given $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups in $G$ such that $H \bigcap K=${$1_G$}

SHOW: $xy = yx$ for all $x \in H$ and $y \in K$

This is what I have so far:

$x \in H$ and $y \in K$

$\therefore g_{1}xg_{1}^{-1}=x$

and $g_{2}yg_{2}^{-1}=y$

for $g_{1}, g_{2} \in G$

$\therefore xy=g_{1}xg_{1}^{-1}g_{2}yg_{2}^{-1}$

$=g_{2}yg_{2}^{-1}g_{1}xg_{1}^{-1}$

$=yx$

is this correct?

Comment: No, that's not correct. You've just asserted that $g_1xg_1^{-1}g_2yg_2^{-1}=g_2yg_2^{-1}g_1xg_1^{-1}$ without giving any justification at all.

Comment: Where does $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ live?

Comment: Hint: You want to prove that $xy=yx$, i.e. that $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=1_G$. One of your hypotheses is of the form "if $g$ satisfies <some conditions>, then $g=1_G$". So try to show that $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ satisfies those conditions.

Comment: See also this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147530/normal-subgroups-that-intersect-trivially).

Answer (score 2):

Prove: A subgroup $\,H\leq G\,$ is normal iff $\,[H,G]:=\langle g^{-1}h^{-1}gh\,\,;\,\,g\in G\,,\,h\in H\rangle \leq H\,$ .

Apply this now to an element $\,[x,y]\in [H,K]\,$ ...

Comment: +1 for the answer, however, it would be better to elaborate it more for him.

Answer (score 2):

Try proving that the term $(xyx^{-1})y^{-1}= x (yx^{-1}y^{-1}) \in H \cap K =\{e\}$

Answer (score 0):

Sorry your proof is not correct. Just because $gHg^{-1}=H$ does not mean that it happens pointwise! Note $gxg^{-1}=x$ will be equivalent to $x$ and $g$ commuting. Since your $g$ is a generic element you've assume the group $G$ is commutative.

Several of the others have suggested better approaches :)

Comment: > "Since your g is a generic element you've assume the group G is commutative."

Actually, it's not quite correct. x can belong to the center of G and G may not be equal to its center.