# group order $p^2q^2$ will be abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

let $(G,*)$ a group order $p^2q^2$ such that $q\nmid p^2 -1  $ y $p\nmid q^2 -1$ then $G$ is abelian.
for Sylow theorem $n_p\equiv 1\mod (p)$ then $n_p = 1, q, q^2 $ but $n_p\neq p^2$ the same form $n_q \neq q^2$ but what next??

Comment: $(q-1)\mid(q^2-1)$, so $p\nmid(q-1)$

Comment: That should be $n_p = 1,q,q^2$ (not $1,p,p^2$).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A group of order $p^2q$ will be abelian](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153657/a-group-of-order-p2q-will-be-abelian)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can show that your group $G$ is as $H\times K$ wherein $H$ and $K$ are normal sylow $p$-subgroup and normal sylow $q$-subgroup respectively. Now, since $H$ and $K$ are abelian groups, so is $G$ itself.Use what Jyrki noted above to show that you have only one sylow $p$-subgroup and one sylow $q$-subgroup.

Comment: Babak & groups = :-)