# If $q$ not congurent to $1 \pmod{p}$, then every group of order $p^2q$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

> Let $p$ and $q$ be prime numbers with $p<q$.
>
> If $q \not\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, then every group of order $p^2q$ is
> abelian.

From the Third Sylow Theorem I found that the number of $p$-Sylow subgroups is 1, and since it's the only one, it is normal, thus is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ or to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

But form here I'm stuck. I know that the number of $q$-Sylow subgroups $n_q \in\{1 , p, p^2\}$. Maybe if I could find that $n_q = 1$, which implies that the $q$-Sylow subgroup is normal, I could find an isomorphism between the group of order $p^2q$ and the direct product of the two Sylow subgroups, but I don't know how to proceed.

I looked also at this question ([A group of order $p^2q$ will be abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153657/a-group-of-order-p2q-will-be-abelian)), but I dont' have the assumption that  $p^2\not\equiv 1\pmod{q}$.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use `$\{ X\}$` for $\{ X\}$.

Comment: $\text{\$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\$}$ might work better for you instead of using a lower-case x.

Comment: Since $p^2-1=(p+1)(p-1)$ and $q$ can divide neither factor, you get the assumption that $p^2\not \equiv 1 \pmod q$ for free so the linked question applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from [the question you linked to](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153657/a-group-of-order-p2q-will-be-abelian)...the assumption that $p^2\not \equiv 1 \pmod q$ comes for free.

To see this note that $p^2-1=(p+1)(q+1)$ so $q\,|\,(p^2-1)\implies  q\,|\,p- 1\,\text{or}\, q\,|\,p+1$.

Since $q>p$ we can't have $q\,|\,p-1$ so we must have $q\,|\,p+1$.  But that only happens when $p=2,q=3$ and in that particular case we have $q\equiv 1 \pmod p$ so this instance is excluded.