Let G be a group of order 45. Explain why the centre of G cannot have order 9 or 15
I am not sure how to
I tried to use the class equation to prove that the centre $Z(G)$ of a group $ G$ of order 45 cannot have order 9 or 15, but I’m struggling with how to proceed, especially since ( G ) is not specified as non-abelian.
I tried to use the class equation:
$$
|G| = |Z(G)| + \sum_{i} [G : C_G(x_i)],
$$
where the sum is over representatives $ x_i $ of the conjugacy classes of $ G $ that are not in the centre, and $ C_G(x_i) $ is the centralizer of $ x_i $.
I tried using this to prove that $|Z(G)|$ couldn't be 20, but I am not sure how to proceed.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You asked the same question here just a few minutes ago. Why are you asking it here again?

I am trying to put up a better post, that explains what I have worked on better

Do you know that if G/Z(G) is cyclic then G is abelian?

I get that now thank you

Is the class equation above not useful at all in this type of question?

Please do not delete then repost; instead, edit the existing question.

The group is abelian. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/153657/104041

Clearly the OP wished to pursue a different approach than the one in the dupe target.

If the center has order $9$ or $15$ then there is no room for the centralizers of the noncentral elements (Lagrange).

If fact, for $g\notin Z(G)$, $Z(G)<C_G(g)<G$. But if $|Z(G)|=9$ there is no proper multiple of $9$ which is also a proper divisor of $45$. And the same if  $|Z(G)|=15$.
